# Redirect output to file returns permission denied

Tags: sudo, redirect

I'm trying to add some files from a file to another but at time to redirecting output the terminal returns me a message of "Denied permission" and I don't know where I should put `sudo`.

I tried with this:

```bsh
sudo cat named.conf.default-zones >>named.conf.local
```

Comment: I didn't see this example in the duplicate: `cat named.conf.default-zones | sudo tee -a named.conf.local`